# How can I update the API call on a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm teaching myself React Hooks, and I want to update the API call when a user types in a search box. Sort of a live search. I've gathered that the event only triggers when the page loads, but how can I solve this?

Sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6x1xp57zmk

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [cardNames, setCardName] = useState([])

  const rezCards = async () => {
    //const rez = await fetch('https://api.scryfall.com/cards?page=3')
    const rez = await fetch ('https://api.scryfall.com/catalog/card-names')
    const json = await rez.json()
    setCardName(json.data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    rezCards()
  },[])

  return <ul>{cardNames
    .slice(0,50)
    .map(
      (cardName) => {
        return <li key={cardName}>{cardName}</li>
      }
    )}</ul>
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something you should take a look. To prevent multiple api calls on typing on search box, use a technique called `debounce`, you can achieve this with react hooks:

```
function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value);
      }, delay);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    },
    [value, delay],
  );

  return debouncedValue;
}

function App() {

  const debouncedInput = useDebounce(searchInputValue, 300);
  useEffect(() => {
    rezCards()
  },[debouncedInput])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    rezCards()
},[])
```

You have left the second argument as empty array, that causing the `useEffect` only run once when the component is mount, just same as `componentDidMount`.

If you wish to trigger the `useEffect` whenever a state is changed, you can add the state as the dependency for the hook, for example

```
const { callThisEffectWhenThisValueIsChanged, changeValue } = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    // Do anything with here, for eg call APIs
},[callThisEffectWhenThisValueIsChanged])

changeValue(newValue);
```

Thus, in your CodeSandbox code, all you need to do is to add your `searchInput` in the dependency and it will call the hook again whenever the search input is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    rezCards();
}, [searchInput]);
```

Always remember that whenever your effect is using any state, you need to add the state as the dependency for the effect hooks

You may find more information in the [React Hook doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: Hey, that works! But it's ADDING to the results instead of replacing it, so it starts with a bunch of Pikachu cards and if I type "charmander" it adds all the cards with "cha" in their names (champion, etc.) and so on as I type more letters. How can I reset the state in there?

Comment: hi @BrianPaskoff if you check the console on your CodeSandbox, you will see a lot of errors of duplicating `key` for render, that's why some of the `<li>` tag will just reuse what the previous value, which is the Pikachu data. Try changing the `<li key={cardName.name}>` to `<li key={cardName.id}>` instead which should be unique

Comment: You can check on https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys for more details on how key works in React

Comment: Wow I didn't know keys were that important, I thought they were identifiers that were _highly suggested_ to be there for code to be more readable but not something that went in to making the whole thing tick. It works now as intended, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, it will cause any undesired output if we are not aware of that :) Remember to upvote the answer if you find it useful! Have a nice day!